# int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType' Django

Tags: python, django

Why am i getting this error here? It very wierd, sometimes it works and sometimes it does not. Can someone explain if they understand.
The error accures in my views.py file:

```
    fotlister = Produkt.objects.filter(under_kategori__navn__iexact="lister")
    kalkuler = ProduktKalkureing.objects.all()
    beregning = {}

    if request.method == "POST":
        omkrets = request.GET.get('omkrets')
        for i in kalkuler:
            kalk = math.ceil((int(omkrets)/i.lengde)*1000)

            add = ({'produkt_tittel': i.produkt.produkt_tittel,
                              'produkt_bilde': i.produkt.produkt_bilde,
                              'produkt_info': i.produkt.produkt_info,
                              'produkt_link': i.produkt.produkt_link,
                              'pris_heltall': i.produkt.pris_heltall,
                              'antall_kalk': kalk,
                              'total_kost': kalk * i.produkt.pris_heltall
                              })
            beregning.update(add)
```

What im trying to do is get the value from a POST request and calculate based on that value. Also i would like to put all the values into a dictionary, also having trouble with that. All i would like to put all the information in the add dictionary and display that on my template. Thanks for any answers, im just trying to understand how python operates.

Comment: The `omkrets` parameter is not being passed to your view. Try `print(request.GET)` to see what's in it.

Comment: I think you also meant to do `beregning = []` then later `beregning.append(add)`. You should read the Python tutorial https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/ it covers using dictionaries https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Comment: thanks mate, i used request.GET['omkrets'], that seemd to do the trick!

Comment: Yes but then how do i display that in the order i want to? what happens now is only the last value gets added.

Comment: `.update` overwrites a dictionary with the values of another dictionary. If you want a dictionary of dictionaries you need a key for the dictionary, for example `beregning[i.produkt.tittel] = add`. Or use a list, as I already suggested.

Comment: What order do you want?

Comment: If you want it ordered by `kalk` and you make it list as I suggested earlier you can do something like `print(sorted(beregning, key=lambda x: x["antall_kalk"]))`

Comment: Il try to explain this as best as best as i can. I want to store the data im making in that dict for every produkt i have in my database. Then i want to render all the data for each product on the template.